# Access forbidden, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com on metaplex candymachine?

Tags: rpc, solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I deployed an nft collection on solana using metaplex and candymachine. It was working fine for 4-5 days now suddenly I am receiving this error. I was able to connect wallet and mint fine for a couple of days. I am not sure what's wrong now what I am getting 403 from rpc pool?

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to get balance of account
> : Error: 403 Forbidden:  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":
> 403, "message":"Access forbidden, contact your app developer or
> support@rpcpool.com."}, "id": "" }

Comment: After mailing the support it came to my knowledge that the mainnet-beta RPC owner limited the calls.  And since I was using a free rpc pool. I can not do anything about it and have to go for a paid rpc. I just hope it does not require me to re-upload the collection cause it cost sols.  And this limitation should be mentioned on solana docs from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Metaplex and NFT calls are not allowed on the free RPCs. You'll have to use a paid provider or go with https://api.metaplex.solana.com/

If you're doing any sort of NFT drop, it is still recommended to get a paid RPC.

You shouldn't have to re-upload again, as long as you did successfully on the other RPC.

Comment: where do you find these other RPC's?